# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/json/JSONObject"

Tags: java, json, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

when I build my code locally with maven, I don't have a error. 
But when I go up the code on karaf ServiceMix, my bundle remains at "FAILURE"

Error Stack :

```
karaf@root>Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-83" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/springframework/osgi/context/internal/classloader/ChainedClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/json/JSONObject"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/springframework/osgi/context/internal/classloader/ChainedClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/json/JSONObject"
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy285.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ProxyUtils$1.run(ProxyUtils.java:65)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ProxyUtils.createProxy(ProxyUtils.java:62)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ProxyUtils.createProxy(ProxyUtils.java:39)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.AbstractServiceProxyCreator.createServiceProxy(AbstractServiceProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.createProxy(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:206)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.getObject(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:166)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Exception.
I used to Memcached in my application, and after the restart a whole servicemix problem was gone. Maybe it would be helpfull